# How to change the cmd.exe output into English on German system

Tags: windows

On German platform, by default, run command line "systeminfo", the output is in German.

But, I need it to output in English.

So, I run "chcp 437" to change the code page to United States.

But, it doesn't work.

(the same approach works on Japanese platform)

Any one can help this?

Comment: Which Windows Version?

Comment: In the title you write you want cmd.exe Output in english, in the question you want systeminfo.exe Output in english. Please adjust title and question to match what you want.

Comment: This question is marked as duplicated but it is actually a different question, and it is unanswered.